# How can i fix "Import "pandas" could not be resolved from source PylancereportMissingModuleSource"?

Tags: python, pandas

I'm having this problem:
"Import "pandas" could not be resolved from sourcePylancereportMissingModuleSource"
I realty don't know why or the meaning of it. I've worked with pandas before but it's the first time i'm having this kind of problem.
I have tried some "solutions" that i've found but the problem persists.

1. pandas in c:\users...\site-packages (1.4.1)
2. numpy>=1.18.5 in c:\users...\site-packages (from pandas) (1.22.3)
3. pytz>=2020.1 in c:\users...\site-packages (from pandas) (2021.3)
4. python-dateutil>=2.8.1 in c:\users...\site-packages (from pandas) (2.8.2)
5. six>=1.5 in c:\users...\site-packages (from python-dateutil>=2.8.1->pandas) (1.16.0)

Comment: Have you tried uninstalling and then reinstalling?

Comment: Just in case, If you have created a virtual environment for the project, you will need to reinstall `pandas` into that virtual environment again.